# How to fetch info from TFS REST API using Python?

Tags: python, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've manage to fetch Project names with:

```py
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

def get_project_names(token):
   # Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
   personal_access_token = token
   organization_url = '<url>'

   # Create a connection to the org
   credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
   connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

   # Get a client (the "core" client provides access to projects, teams, etc)
   core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()

   # Get the list of projects in the org
   projects = core_client.get_projects()

   # Get Project names
   names = []

   for project in projects:
      projects_names = project.__dict__["name"]
      names.append(projects)

   return names
```

Luckily the sample at https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api provided almost everything for that.

Their documentation is very good: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testplan/test%20%20plans/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Now I need to fetch info about our Test Plans. I've searched through the docs and looked at samles at their Github, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any particular error message? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this library, but looking at the example and taking a quick glance at the source it seems as though you would need to use the `connection.clients.get_test_client()` and then use the methods on that [TestClient](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/azure-devops/azure/devops/released/test/test_client.py) class.

But be sure to target the correct classes for the correct API version you're trying to access. I see there are 3 different namespaces: `released`, `v5_0`, `v5_1`. There are `ClientFactory` classes in each of them.

Other than this, I think you can use just about any generic http library to make the REST requests as long as you're providing the PAT in the Authentication header.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Looks like I need to reverse engineer their code a lot if i'm going to be able to do this from a simple script. Not too fimiliar with decorators. I've tried to put everything that is dependent in a single file. Can you take a look at this?

https://pastebin.com/bZAH4unf

Comment: I'm not very seasoned in my python skills, but if the client library you're using is too much to chew on for the reverse engineering you're talking about, you could use the [Azure DevOps REST API specs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/tree/master/specification) and [editor.swagger.io](https://editor.swagger.io/) to trim the client to include only what you want. The generated Readme.md files have been helpful for me. This article is a good [getting started](https://fizzylogic.nl/2018/09/26/learn-how-to-quickly-generate-rest-clients-from-swagger-files/).